# Equivalent of 'more' or 'less' command in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to paginate output by piping it to a `more` or `less` command, similar to [those that are available in Linux\Unix shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/81131/87389)?

Comment: For those who don't know less, some cool things about it is that you can go backwards, use arrows, use page up/down and even search using the key '/' and have the results highlighted.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Well... There is "more", which is more or less (...) the same you'd expect from other platforms. Try the following example:

```
dir -rec | more
```

Comment: more does exactly that, when you take a look at the definition of the function with gcm more|select Definition|fl

Comment: Actually, piping to more is equal to piping to "out-host -paging", which is separate from the more.com implementation. In practice there is no discernable difference though.

Comment: Neither in PS1 on Vista nor PS2 on Win7, at least for me. "more" is a function which does a little work beforehand and then just calls more.com. Out-Host -Paging is separate from that (and doesn't depend on more.com). The difference is most noticeable when you use something that doesn't return right away, such as your gci -rec example. Piping to Out-Host is immediate, as it can process the input one line at a time, piping to more takes time as PS first collects all lines and then sends them to more.com.

Comment: Interesting! For me, gcm more returns two definitions, one is a PowerShell function that, when given an empty argument, does "$input | out-host -p", which is the behavior I'm seeing on gci -rec | more. On the other hand, when I do gci -rec | more.com, I get the normal more.com behavior.

On W7 RC with PS2 installed, I also seem to get more.com even when typing just "more". On Vista with PS1, the behavior described above occurs. Based on http://huddledmasses.org/powershell-power-user-tips-get-command-precedence/, wouldn't you think the function should be executed on W7 also? Hmm...

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't particularly well-written. So my point was that on Vista with PowerShell 1, piping to just "more" invokes Out-Host -p while on W7 with PowerShell 2 it invokes more.com.

Comment: Eep, I stand corrected. Sorry. Yes, indeed, in PS 1 it invokes Out-Host -p, not more.com (note to self: Always read the whole function, even if it looks very similar)

Comment: more lacks features such as moving backwards, moving forward with `f` and filtering and searching.

Comment: Thank you. This answer saved my life and I could actually do stuff while stuck on Windows!

Answer (score 146):

Yes there is:

`some-cmdlet | out-host -paging`

Comment: I had used more and less before, neither being quite as user friendly as I should think possible. I found this variation to be more useful/usable than the others. Thanks very much.

Comment: For printing the content of a very large file this worked very nice for me as the Get-Content cmdlet started immedialety to pipe the contents to the out-host cmdlet.

Comment: Note that the -Paging parameter of Out-Host is not supported in the PowerShell ISE.

Comment: @BrunoBrant That's not the point. You could pipe the output to anything; `less` is just a big text viewer application that accepts `stdin` for the text. You could pipe it to a temp file and open it in `nano` or `vim` for EVEN MOAR POWERRRR! Not the point. PowerShell is like `bash` (but better, imho). `less` is not in `bash`; it's a separate binary. So your criticism is not valid.

Comment: @AlanMcBee, I must love flamebait: 1) "you could pipe the output to anything": yep, and as you said, that's not the point. 2) "Powershell is like bash": and like cmd, and like any other shell ever made. But powershell is object oriented and not text based, which is a GREAT difference. 3) "less is not in bash". So what? Did I mentioned bash? If I was building a shell I'd do my user a favor of including a less-like tool. That's all I was saying.

Comment: @BrunoBrant re flamebait: I know the feeling. Sorry. But less is not bundled w PS (nor CMD), so your comment felt more like a "Windows sucks" snub than anything helpful (although I agree that `less` is A Very Cool Thing, if you can't use PS ;-) ). The OO feature is not a detriment; you can always treat text like an object if you want. OO lets you work with streams over several pipes in more powerful ways than text, if you want. All said, however, I totally agree that PS would be better if it had `less` in it.

Comment: Also, comment on the answer: the alias `oh` is for `Out-Host`, and parameters can be abbreviated if there's no conflict, so the command could be `Some-Cmdlet | oh -p`

Comment: @AlanMcBee The point is that most Unix-like distributions includes the “less” pager, but Windows doesn’t provide an equivalent pager. I currently pipe it into the less in my MinGW64, but it doesn’t feel native.

Comment: @TheXenocide How is out-host -paging more useful/usable than the others?

Comment: @brendan Wish I could tell you, but I honestly don't remember; that comment is from 9 years ago :-/

Comment: This is not About recursion here, but if one is interested in the [`-rec`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6) alias, see the link.

Comment: out-host is not available for me on Win 10

Answer (score 46):

`dir -rec | more` is bad advice.

It will cause powershell to evaluate the entire command prior to outputting it to the screen, something that is not needed for something like output paginating

In some extreme cases, it could cause the system to crash (e.g. `dir 'C:\' | more`)

On the other hand, using `out-host -paging` will output information to the screen as it is available.

Comment: When you use remote powershell and want to pipe a command on the remote windows server through a pager, piping through

`out-host -paging`

works as desired.  Piping through `more` when running the remote command is of no use: the entire text is displayed at once.

Comment: The alias for `out-host -paging` is `oh -pa`.

Answer (score 43):

The [Powershell Community Extensions](https://github.com/Pscx/Pscx) have a handy function named 'less' that provides a more complete Unix-style feature set, using a ported copy of less.exe to actually handle the paging.

You can install it by starting an **admin shell** and running:

```
Find-Package pscx | Install-Package -Force
```

(the `force` is to upgrade older versions)

If you don't have the admin rights, you can install it for the current user :

```
Find-Package pscx | Install-Package -Force -scope currentuser -allowclobber
```

You can pipe strings to it, or give filenames as direct parameters.

```
type foo.txt | less
less foo.txt, bar.txt, baz.txt
```

It works in ConEmu and Powershell windows, but unfortunately it doesn't work the way you'd expect under the v2.0 ISE.

Comment: The installation overrides several basic Powershell commands (gcb,Expand-Archive,Format-Hex,Get-Hash,help,prompt,Get-Clipboard,Get-Help,Set-Clipboard) so saying "the `force` is to upgrade older versions" seems a little bit misleading.

Comment: just installing for current user without errors or warnings use: `Find-Package pscx | Install-Package -Force -scope currentuser -allowclobber`

Comment: Thanks for the awesome tip!

Comment: `-allowclobber` seems to be required in current powershell versions

Answer (score 26):

I prefer the "less" command over the "more" command. With the less command, results can also be paged backwards instead of just forwards.

The "less" from [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) works for me*

To save typing I added the alias "l" for less in my Powershell profile (`notepad $profile`):

```
Set-Alias -Name "l" -Value "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Git\bin\less.exe"
```

Look for `less` either in the above path or `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\less.exe` or similar.

---

*: I had errors in Powershell with the [Gow](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki) version of "less".

Comment: Me too. Besides paging backwards, less allows me to perform text search on the result (forward slash, then type text, then press enter, then 'n' for next result, 'p' for previous result). Very, very, convenient.

Comment: Another `less` fan here. But I get this error. Any advice?
________________________________________
```PS C:\Users\oli> Get-Content tmpf | out-host 'C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\less.exe'
Out-Host : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\less.exe'.
At line:1 char:20
+ Get-Content tmpf | out-host 'C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\less.exe'
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Out-Host], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutHostCommand```

Comment: @olisteadman, This is the official Git version of less.exe. Have you tried the Git for Windows https://gitforwindows.org/ version of less?

Comment: No need to use "out-host". I use this: "Get-Content tmpf | C:\cygwin64\bin\less.exe"

Comment: It is also a very good idea to set $env:PAGER="C:\cygwin64\bin\less.exe", so it will be used for example when you type "help"

Comment: Works great as git's `core.pager` config!

Comment: In my 2018 installation, the folder is `...\Git\usr\bin`. I added the folder to my PATH and got hundreds of Linux commands in my PS.

Answer (score 6):

```
PS> cd C:\

PS> dir -r -ex 0 | out-Host -paging

PS> dir -file -r -ea 0 c:\Windows | Select FullName,Length,LastWriteTime | out-gridview
```

Answer (score 5):

`more` isn't used to *limit* output, it's used to *paginate* output and make it easier to read in a terminal, if anything.

Are you talking about using `head` and `tail`?   [EggHeadCafe](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/conversation.aspx?messageid=29676243&threadid=29676239) has an example of:

```
type my.txt | select-object -first 10

type my.txt | select-object -last 10
```

to emulate `head` and `tail`.

Comment: Piping is extremely slow for large files. There are better ways (built-in options) to do `head` and `tail` in powershell now: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41626586/1081043

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use less through the [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/):

```
some-cmdlet | wsl less
```

Comment: Note that this only works if your default WSL distribution is WSL1.  WSL2 distributions run into the problem mentioned in [these](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4754) [two](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4646) Github issues.  It's also possible to specify a WSL1 distribution manually in the command-line with `-d <distro>`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have VIM installed, I thoroughly enjoy `dir -r | vim -R -`. Unfortunately this suffers the same problem with `more` (ie. no streaming).

Answer (score 2):

```
cat C:\Temp\test.txt
```

cat is an alias for Get-Content - with larger files you will get the -- More -- output at the bottom of the terminal

You can also you can add -wait

```
cat C:\Temp\test.txt -wait
```

-wait is like using tail but it actually is rerunning the command just refreshing the output

```
cat C:\Temp\test.txt | oh –Paging
```

oh = Out-Host

Answer (score 1):

I added a function definition and alias to my default profile at
`%SystemRoot%\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\profile.ps1`

This function is mostly based on [this blog entry by Aman Dhally](http://www.amandhally.net/2012/01/09/creating-more-in-powershell/) with added exception handling for pressing `Q` while paging.

```
function more2
{
   param(
     [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
     [System.Management.Automation.PSObject]$InputObject
   )

   begin
   {
      $type = [System.Management.Automation.CommandTypes]::Cmdlet
      $wrappedCmd = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand(‘Out-Host’, $type)
      $scriptCmd = {& $wrappedCmd @PSBoundParameters -Paging }
      $steppablePipeline = $scriptCmd.GetSteppablePipeline($myInvocation.CommandOrigin)
      $steppablePipeline.Begin($PSCmdlet)
   }

   process
   {
      try
      {
         $steppablePipeline.Process($_)
      }
      catch
      {
        break;
      }
   }

   end
   {
      $steppablePipeline.End()
   }

   #.ForwardHelpTargetName Out-Host
   #.ForwardHelpCategory Cmdlet
}

New-Alias more more2
```

so I can just call it like `dir -r | more` and it *immediately* starts paged output because of PowerShell's pipeline (as opposed to waiting for the complete output with more.com).

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly this question (well I wanted less, not more) and found the answer of @richard-berg worked for me, being new to PowerShell (but not to Linux), I found the things missing from that answer (for me) were:
I first needed to go:
`Find-Package pscx | Install-Package`
which then prompted for "installing nuget package". I did this but then had to use the 
`-AllowClobber` parameter on `Install-Package`.
then in order to use less, I had to:
`Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`
which all worked :-)

Comment: Welcome to the site. Not sure what you mean by "answer #24". Those numbers are votes (which can change) rather than enumeration.

Comment: Ah, I see ... first time I've posted to stack overflow! I meant the answer of @richard-berg, for me, that would have been the accepted answer

Comment: Not sure why I get a down vote? Seems (to me) it is helpful to confirm when something has worked!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do in my opinion is to use [Scoop](https://scoop.sh/) to install anything you're used to using from UNIX. Once you do, just run `scoop install less` and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: Put the file into a temporary/disposable .txt file, then let the OS invoke your favorite editor, the one that is linked to the .txt extension.

Get-Process | Out-File temp.txt ; .\temp.txt

Note: each time you use this you will overwrite any pre-existent temp.txt file.
Pick the file name wisely.

The above is just a basic idea.
Next step would be transforming this into "| more" using aliases or profile functions, etc.

HTH,
Marcelo Finkielsztein

Answer (score 0):

The easiest/most elegant in-built way of paging output without relying on non-standard utilities is to pipe the output through the `Out-Host` utility. Usually, all output goes through this utility by default but, if manually specified, you can add the `-Paging` option that provides similar functionality to `less` or `more` under Unix-based OS:

```
Get-Content a_very_long_file.txt | Out-Host -Paging
```

PowerShell has many predefined aliases. In this case, this can be shortened to:

```
gc a_very_long_file.txt | oh -P
```

which means exactly the same (`gc` == `Get-Content`; `oh` == `Output-Host`)

To read more about the `Out-Host` utility:

```
Get-Help Out-Host
```