Windows PowerShell shortcut to scroll to previous command
The various scroll commands in PowerShell don't seem to offer an option for scrolling to the previous command, i.e. to the top of the previous output.
So if I've executed a series of commands, each with a slew of output, and I want to review the most recent output from the top, wherever the top may be, my options include:

scroll up/down one line at a time
scroll up/down one page at a time
scroll to top/bottom of history/buffer

I don't know how long the output from the previous command is, so I'm just scrolling and scanning, scrolling and scanning. It's the most inefficient task of all time :-/
Is there actually a solution for this, just not well known?
Bonus: do other command line tools have an equivalent shortcut?

Looking for a scroll option, understanding that an alternative is to output to file instead.

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1083771/447901

@lit thanks but more isn't what I'm looking for -- it also alters the output and might cause other problems; a simple shortcut is what I'm after

The answer refers to Out-Host -Paging. Have you tried that?

What are the "various scroll commands in PowerShell"?

@MathiasR.Jessen https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-keyboard.html

What if the output of the previous command exceeds the screen buffer's capacity? Would you want to keep the output stored in memory so you can render it again without running the command again?

@lit not seeing how Out-Host -Paging helps achieve the objective: it provides a nice paging interface, but doesn't make it easier to return to the the top of output.

@MathiasR.Jessen in that case I'd pipe to file, but I'm looking for a shortcut that scrolls to the previous command (when it's in the current buffer)

Note:

This answer is not a general terminal-related answer; it is specific to Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal.


Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal offers a shell integration feature  that is enabled by default and supports a number of shells, including PowerShell (open the Settings view (Ctrl+,) and type shell integration to see all relevant settings).
With this feature enabled (as is the case by default):

In terms of keyboard shortcuts, Ctrl+↑ scrolls back to the prompt at which the previous command was submitted.

Generally, you can use Ctrl+↑  and Ctrl+↓ to navigate between command submissions.


In terms of GUI features (which too are enabled by default):

In the so-called gutter, the area to the left of the terminal display, each submitted command is visually indicated by a small blue dot.

When you manually scroll upward, a blue dot appearing will indicate where a command was submitted.


In the so-called overview ruler, which is a visually enhanced scroll bar to the right of the terminal, each submitted command is represented by a blue rectangle

Clicking on such a blue rectangle will scroll to that command submission.






The following screenshot illustrates the above-mentioned GUI features: note the blue dots in the gutter on the LHS, and the blue squares in the overview ruler (scroll bar) on the RHS.


you responded to my comment but my comment has disappeared -- does not appear in any of the SO activity.  gremlins

@user9375338: Conversational comments that have served their purpose once the intended recipients have (hopefully) seen them are routinely deleted by moderators, assisted by users who can flag such comment as "It's no longer needed." I don't remember the specifics of your comment, but based on my response (which I've now also deleted, knowing that you've seen it), I assume it was a thank-you (which I appreciated). If there was also technical feedback in there that may have been of interest to future readers, consider posting that part (only) again.

got it!  seems like all of these comments fall into that conversational category, thanks for explaining.
